# maven 2.2.1 release prepare custom tag format

Tags: maven, release

Configuration Management team at my workplace mandates 4 digit version numbers for artefacts - say, 1.2.3.4 - for released artefact and 1.2.3.5-SNAPSHOT for development pom

In addition to this, our version control system (clearcase) has pre-label trigger which enforces a certain naming convention for label/tag.

So, if the pom version is 1.2.3.4-SNAPSHOT and artifactId is, for instance, shopcart then, as per the tag naming requirement, tag name should be:

XXX_1.2.3_SHOPCART_DROP4_SRC

where XXX is project code - constant string value.

As you see, in order to achieve this format, I need to make following customisations to tag name format:

- artifactId - convert to uppercase
- first 3 digits of 4 digit version number to be extracted
- last digit of 4 digit version number to be extracted
- concatenate everything as per the format.

I thought I would use gmaven plugin to get this done and populate a custom property to be used in tag or tagNameFormat configuration property of maven release plugin (v2.3.2) - but that doesn't work at all.

maven release plugin supports only 3 properties (artifactId, version, groupId) and doesn't support any other property.

gmaven plugin works as expected and sets a final user property in the tag name format I need - I verified it using the ant run maven plugin to echo the property.

Problem is with maven release plugin - it doesn't understand any user property...

Can anyone help how can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

Interactive run is not a possibility - need to configure this to run for about 15 projects on jenkins ...

Many thanks,
Tapasvi

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation of the maven-release-plugin carefully cause there is a parameter which can be used for such purposes. The [tagNameFormat](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#tagNameFormat) which can be used to change the format of the tag which will be created (Oh sorry. You already read that). The version can extract into properties via the [buildhelper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html). Furthermore the buildhelper-maven-plugin can be used to make uppercase of the artifact id:

Set a property by applying a regex replacement to a value

The regex-property goal can be used to set a property to a value after regex replacement has been applied. For example, executing the following plugin configuration to set the clearcase.artifact property.

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>regex-property</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>regex-property</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <name>clearcase.artifactid</name>
              <value>$\{project.artifactId}</value>
              <regex>(.*)</regex>
              <replacement>???</replacement>
              <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

But you need to be carefull about setting properties, cause release:perform fork a Maven process. You might need to use the -Darguments option to set the appropriate parameters.

Comment: How does this help? This is another way of setting the property - I was using gmaven plugin. Problem is, properties set by any other plugin (build helper or gmaven) are not visible to maven release plugin...this is because when I invoke release:prepare lifecycle properties are not available ...

Comment: Just use the options like [arguments](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#arguments) of the maven-release-plugin to give those properties to the invoked instance of Maven during the release cyclce.